# Access Element in ControlTemplate from Style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, controltemplate

I want to `Style` an `Border` inside a `ControlTemplate`. But I don't know how to access it. My `Style` looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="RedCell" TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource MYDGCellStyle}">            
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid Grid.ZIndex="86" x:Name="CellContenGrind" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />                            
                        <Border Grid.ZIndex="87" x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="White" Background="Crimson" CornerRadius="25">
                            <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>                            
                        <Grid Grid.ZIndex="88"  x:Name="CellGridFocused"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="CellGridFocused" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_DataGridCellFocused}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="CellContenGrind" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_DataGridSelected}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ungelesen}" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I need the `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` on my *CellContentGrind* because of some other stuff, so I can't just move that to my `Border`.

If *ungelesen* = 0, I want the `Background` of my *ContentBorder* to be Green. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not move the Style to the Border itself?

```
<Border Grid.ZIndex="87"x:Name="ContentBorder" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="25">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Crimson" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ungelesen}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>                 
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>

    <ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

Note that Background is set with Setter now to make overridable with DataTrigger.